# Not able to pass values from Java code to JSP

Tags: java, database, jsp

I am trying to connect to a database and display the values read from the database column in a JSP table. For this I created a Java class that can connect to the database and read the values I need in a local class variable. Now on the JSP side, I am creating an object of the class and trying to retrieve the values from the database. On JSP side I am not getting the values in the Java class variable. However when I run the Java class standalone, I am able to display the database values. Just that I am not able to effectively pass the values to the JSP. Here is my code:

```
JSP:

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="com.mypckg.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        DBConnect dbCon = new DBConnect();
        String[] Codes = dbCon.getCode().split("##");
    %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Code</td>
        </tr>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < Codes.length; i++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%
                    dbCon.getName();
                %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%
                    dbCon.getCode();
                %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your `DBConnect` class ? You should retrieve the value from the java class, and then send the value to the jsp page through `setAttribute`. It is better for the maintenance purpose

Comment: This is my DbConnect class:.

Comment: This is my DbConnect class:
package com.mypckg;
public class DBConnect {
 private String Name = "";
 private String Code = "";
 public DBConnect() {
  fetchfromDB();
 }
 public void fetchfromDB() {  
  //REMOVED LOGIC TO CONNECT TO DB TO SHORTEN THE CODE FOR FORUM POSTING}
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from TABLE");
   rset = pstmt.executeQuery();   
   if (rset != null) {
    while (rset.next()) {
     setCode(rset.getString(reldataCodeColumn));
     setName(rset.getString(reldataNameColumn));    
    }
   }   
 }

Comment: you need to edit your question and post the code there

Comment: public String getName() {
    return Name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
    Name = Name.concat(name+"##");
   }
   public String getCode() {
    return Code;
   }
   public void setCode( String code) {
    Code = Code.concat(code+"##");
   } 
  }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<%
   dbCon.getName();
%>
```

try using

```
<%= dbCon.getName(); %>
```

(and of course the same for dbCon.getCode())

This is the tag used when you wish to simply output the return value of a method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a statement to executed you can use <% java command %> 
if you want a value to be printed use <%= java command %>

using java commands in that wat is not a good practice ...
refer jstl tags ...that is more efficient and secure way :) ...